# How to determine, if folder has custom icon?

Tags: windows, winapi, icons, directory

How to determine, if the folder of given path has the generic folder icon, or rather custom one, set by user? I would like to use only Win32 API calls.

I know, that I can check, if there is a desktop.ini file inside, but this method is not always available (program may not have permissions to list folder's contents) and slow, because requires parsing the ini file each time (icon may not be changed).

Comment: What's the point of this?  Do favor SHGetFileInfo()

Comment: I wish to display whole filesystem tree, so I have to store icons in some kind of image list. Usually ~ 98% folders has the standard, generic folder icon and only 2% has custom icon. I would have to store hundreds or thousands of same icons on that list absolutely pointlessly.

Comment: The OS manages a system-level image list for its own UI purposes. You can use `SHGetFileInfo()` to access that image list and get indexes of filesystem items within that image list. Simply include the `SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX` flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to "list the folder contents".  The file is always named `desktop.ini`.  If you have the folder path, simply append that filename to it and attempt to open the file.  If it fails, `GetLastError()` will tell you why, either because the file does not exist or you do not have access to it.

Comment: OK, but I **do not** want to do it by parsing desktop.ini, as I clearly stated in question! For instance, SHGetFileInfo will return valid icon even if I don't have permissions to list the folder contents (= access the files in folder). I'm seeking for clear WinAPI way to solve this problem.

Comment: You just answered your own question - use `SHGetFileInfo()` if it works. So what's the problem?

Comment: I do it by P/Invoke in C#. I don't want to keep icons with "borrowed" handles, so I clone them immediately after getting by SHGetFileInfo() and then free. This way even the same icons are duplicated on my list each time I request them, and this is exactly what I wish to prevent.

Comment: `SHGetFileInfo()` gives you a handle to the system image list and the index of a file/folder's icon within that image list. You can either keep that single handle and use the icon indexes as needed, or you can least keep track of each icon index along with your clones so you don't make a new clone for an index you have already cloned.